# Does libc++ counting_semaphore have deadlock issue?

Tags: c++, semaphore, c++20, libc++, stdatomic

[libc++ `counting_semaphore::release`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/617ad14060dcdfa9f1f967a3edd9e097de8bf83a/libcxx/include/semaphore#L86-L94):

```cpp
    void release(ptrdiff_t __update = 1)
    {
        if(0 < __a.fetch_add(__update, memory_order_release))
            ;
        else if(__update > 1)
            __a.notify_all();
        else
            __a.notify_one();
    }
```

Notifies only if internal count was zero before increment, notifies more then one waiter only if increment is more than one.

[libc++ `counting_semaphore::acquire`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/617ad14060dcdfa9f1f967a3edd9e097de8bf83a/libcxx/include/semaphore#L96-L103):

```cpp
    void acquire()
    {
        auto const __test_fn = [=]() -> bool {
            auto __old = __a.load(memory_order_relaxed);
            return (__old != 0) && __a.compare_exchange_strong(__old, __old - 1, memory_order_acquire, memory_order_relaxed);
        };
        __cxx_atomic_wait(&__a.__a_, __test_fn);
    }
```

Waits for count to be non-zero, and tries to CAS it with decremented value.

Now please look into the following 3-threaded case:

```
counting_semaphore<10> s;

T1: { s.acquire(); /*signal to T3*/ }
T2: { s.acquire(); /*signal to T3*/ }
T3: { /*wait until both signals*/ s.release(1); s.release(1); }
```

Initially:

```
__a == 0
```

(`desired` parameter passed as 0, any attempt to `acquire` would block)

Timeline

```
T1: enters wait
T2: enters wait
T3: fetch add 1 & returns 0, now __a == 1
T3: (0 < 0) is false, so notify_one happens
T1: unblocks from wait
T3: fetch add 1 & returns 1, now __a == 2
T3: (0 < 1) is true, so no notification
T1: loads 2
T1: cas 2 to 1 successfully
T1: returns from acquire
T2: still waits despite __a == 1
```

Does this look like a valid deadlock?

---

*why I am asking here instead of reporting the issue?*

I reported the [issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/46357) quite some time ago, no reply so far.
I want to understand if there's indeed a deadlock or I am missing something.

Comment: I'd say, assuming the appropriate memory barriers, the validity of this implementation depends *entirely* on what lives behind `notify_one` and `__cxx_atomic_wait`. It is entirely possible that the implementation of `notify_one` halts execution until any callbacks of `__cxx_atomic_wait` which were notified have completed. But since these internal things are... internal, only the implementer can know one way or the other.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the implementation that would block in `notify_one` is not viable as `std::atomic::notify_one` implementation, and also since we have `desired` set to 0, and the template parameter is 10, we can make up to 10 `release` calls earlier than acquire, and none of them is expected to block.

Comment: "*the implementation that would block in notify_one*" What do you mean by "block"? The implementation would simply execute the atomic_wait callback functor(s). That's a finite operation, so why would it be considered "blocking"? It's also an implementation detail, so it's dealer's choice.

Comment: Ah, see your point, I misunderstood it. I've inspected `__cxx_atomic_wait` and it doesn't seem to halt `notify_one`, as it is possible that it will do the OS wait in `__libcpp_atomic_wait`, which is the usual futex `syscall(SYS_futex, __ptr, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, __val, &__timeout, 0, 0);`. So apparently no, `notify_one` is not synchronized with functor in `__cxx_atomic_wait`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional `if (0 < ...)` is a problem, but it's not the *only* problem.

The [effects of `release`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/thread.sema.cnt#9) are stated to be:

> Atomically execute counter += update. Then, unblocks any threads that are waiting for counter to be greater than zero.

Note the words "any threads". Plural. This means that, even if a particular `update` value happened to be 1, all of the threads blocked on this condition *must* be notified. So calling `notify_one` is wrong, unless the implementation of `notify_one` always unblocks all waiting threads. Which would be an... interesting implementation of that function.

Even if you change `notify_one` to `notify_all`, that doesn't fix the problem. The logic of the condition basically assumes that thread notification should only happen if all of the threads (logically) notified by a previous `release` have escaped from their `acquire` calls. The standard requires no such thing.

Comment: I think that not notifying any threads but just one thread would have been fine under _as if_ rule, if it can be proved that in no circumstances the difference in behavior can be observed, but apparently it did not work.